# Why are bootstrap columns breaking off onto new lines?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Here is my code:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background: #EFEFEF;
}

.container-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-color: #848484
}

.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-left: 20px
}

#post-container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-color: #FF0000
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar"> <img class="navbar-brand" src="images/Ventr_Logo.svg" alt="Ventr Logo" width="100"> </nav>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-2" style="background: #4E4E4E"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-8" id="post-container">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-2" style="background: #4E4E4E"></div>
  </div>
```

The light gray column with the red border is the main column.
Here is what it looks like when the browser is at the approximate size of a tablet, it is properly maintaining the ratio of 6:3 I want. With the 6 being the size of the main column and 3 being the size of the side columns. [This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpYKS.png)

**Now here is the problem:**
 [this is what it looks like on a cell phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79tKB.png)
. The problem is that instead of seeing 3 columns on one line maintaining a ratio of 8:2, like I want it to. Instead, it breaks of onto 3 columns.

**How do I solve this issue?** By the way, I want the columns to have different sizes depending on the size of the screen.

Comment: I *think* the problem arises due to you mixing Bootstrap styles with your own styles, one of which is `border`. The `col-` prefixes denote very specific widths for your columns at the corresponding breakpoints; adding even a few pixels of `border` will likely push them onto the next row. Bootstrap styles like `.container-fluid`, `.row`, `.col-` etc. should be reserved specifically for the framework, and never have styling applied. Your own rules should apply to elements *within*. For example, you could make `#post-container` an element that is a child of the `<div>` it currently is.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap, "col-sm" starts at 768 pixels. To target small screens, you can use "col-xs" (576 pixels or more) or "col" for even smaller screens.

Just replace "col-sm-2" by "col-2" :

```html
  <div class="row" >
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-2" style="background: #4E4E4E"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-8" id="post-container">
    </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-2" style="background: #4E4E4E"></div>
</div>
```